# What is the best way to create an index on 3 column and if this is possible?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb-10.3

We have a SQL query that is doing a full table scan:

```sql
DELETE 
  FROM oc_cart 
 WHERE (api_id > ? OR customer_id = ?) 
   AND date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? HOUR)
```

Is it possible to create an index to optimize this query?

For now I have create 2 indices:

- one on date_added
- one on (date_added, customer_id and api_id)

But it seems that the query is still doing full scan.

Comment: The index on date_added is redundant. (I think I'm right in sayng that) The other index is only partially usable. If (date_added, customer_id) doesn't help, try (date_added,api_id), and try swapping around the order of indexes. You could take a more scientific approach, but the permutations here are so few that it'll be quicker just to 'suck it and see'

Answer (score 0):

How many rows in the table?  What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` provide`?`  EXPLAIN SELECT ...`?

It is not possible to optimize the query much.

*If* `api_id > ?` is more selective than `date added < ...`, then this may be the best:

```
DELETE 
  FROM oc_cart 
 WHERE api_id > ?
   AND date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? HOUR);
DELETE 
  FROM oc_cart 
 WHERE customer_id = ?
   AND date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? HOUR);
```

together with these two indexes:

```
INDEX(api_id, date_added)
INDEX(customer_id, date_added)
```

In case `api_is not` that selective, also add

```
INDEX(date_added, api_id)  (but _not_ INDEX(date_added))
```